# Javascript async callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

My problem is better explained in code:

```
//This code is triggered before ajax ObBegin. But I need f1 to return a boolean to either cancel or continue the event.
f1();

function f1(){
    $.modalWindow.Open(); //This is an async method, this is where my problem lies.
    //I need to freeze here and wait on a return value from one of the events below.
}

//In the modal window:

//An event which waits for the click event
$('.cancelBtn').click(function(){
    //How do I send false back to f1?
    closeModalWindow();
});

$('.yesBtn').click(function(){
    //How do I send true back to f1?
    closeModalWindow();
});
```

So basically what happens is this:

1. `openModalWindow()` opens a modal window that waits on a button click.
2. I want to pass the value back to f1 and return it.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Do you realize that `f2` doesn't actually return anything?

Comment: @Matt Ball, I know, because I have no idea how to return something from an async function.

Comment: You don't - you run a callback function (like @Alex's answer) or something fancier like `jQuery.Deferred` (my answer). But your question is unclear - could you show us some more code?

Comment: @Matt Ball, I edited my question to better show what I want.

Comment: Thanks for the edit - I edited my answer accordingly. I know that it doesn't exactly match the code structure in your question, but it should be pretty workable.

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery's [Deferred objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). There's a good tutorial on it [here](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/using-deferreds-in-jquery/), but you haven't actually shown enough of your own code for me to demonstrate how to wire it up with `$.Deferred`.

---

Here's a very basic demo of how to do this: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/fNQ8J/. Basically, you have to pass callbacks around for asynchronous execution.

```
function openModalWindow(callback) {
    if (typeof callback !== 'function') callback = $.noop;
    $("#dialog-confirm").show().dialog({
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Yes: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                callback(true);
            },
            No: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                callback(false);
            }
        }
    });
}

function f1() {
    return $.Deferred(function(dfd) {
        openModalWindow(dfd.resolve);
    }).promise();
}

$('#clickme').click(function() {
    f1().then(function(result) {
        alert('f1 async returned: ' + result);
    });
});
```

Comment: the last code block of `click` should be an `OnBegin` for an ajax request, which is listening for a return value of true or false.

Comment: unfortunately no :(. The ajax request gets sent anyways because f1 is async and didn't return a true/false (which should tell the `OnBegin` whether or not to send the query.

Comment: You need to put the `OnBegin` inside of the `.then()` callback.

Comment: The ASP.NET MVC part of the question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572573/ajax-beginform-onbegin-confirmation-via-jquery-modal

Answer (score 0):

There's no good way to do this, no. You'll have to refactor `f1` so it can deal with asynchronicity.

Answer (score 0):

`f1()` should be implemented as a callback for `someAsyncFunc()`:

```
function someAsyncFunc(callback) {
    // open your modal window
    $(".theBtm").click(function() {
      // do your stuff
      if (typeof(callback) === "function") {
        callback(theValueYouWantToPass);
      }
    });
}
```

Called something like this:

```
someAsyncFunc(function(value) { f1(value); });
```

Comment: f1() was triggered by an event